# How to make selected function?

Tags: javascript, function

I'm trying to implement a function such that

1. if I press `non2`, then print `text2` in `textarea2`
2. if I then press `pos2`, then print `text2` in `textarea1`.

Here what I want is when I press `pos2` then will be printed in `text2` in `textarea1` and `text2` in `textarea2` will be deleted. Conversely, if I hit `pos2` first and hit `non2` then print only `text2` in `textarea2`.

I was thinking of using an if-else statement to see if one of POS or NON was clicked. This is what I ended up with:

```
<?php
    for ($j = 1; $j <= 3; $j++) {  
        echo '
            <div id="part'. $j .'" >
                <div id="teks'.$j.'">TEXT 2 </div>
                <input type="radio" id="pos'. $j .'" name="teks'.$j.'" value="POS" onclick="addPOS(this.previousElementSibling.innerHTML);">POS2</input>
                <input type="radio" id="non'. $j .'" name="teks'.$j.'" value="NON" onclick="addNON(this.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.innerHTML);">NON2</input>
                <input type="radio" id="neg'. $j .'" name="teks'.$j.'" value="NEG" checked="checked" onclick="delPOS(document.getElementById(\'teks'.$j.'\').innerHTML); delNON(document.getElementById(\'teks'.$j.'\').innerHTML);">NEG2</input>
            </div>
        ';
    }
?>   
<script type="text/javascript">
    function delPOS(elem)
    {
        var txt = document.getElementById("posbox").value;
        if (txt.length>elem.length){
            document.getElementById("posbox").value = txt.substr(0,txt.length-elem.length-1);
        }else{
            document.getElementById("posbox").value="";
        }
    }
    function delNON(elem)
    {
        var txt = document.getElementById("nonbox").value;
        if (txt.length>elem.length){
            document.getElementById("nonbox").value = txt.substr(0,txt.length-elem.length-1);
        }else{
            document.getElementById("nonbox").value="";
        }
    }
    function delNEG(elem)
    {
        var txt = document.getElementById("negbox").value;
        if (txt.length>elem.length){
            document.getElementById("negbox").value = txt.substr(0,txt.length-elem.length-1);
        }else{
            document.getElementById("negbox").value="";
        }
    }

    function addPOS(elem)
    {
        document.getElementById("posbox").value+=elem;
    }
    function addNON(elem)
    {
        document.getElementById("nonbox").value+=elem;
    }
    function addNEG(elem)
    {
        document.getElementById("negbox").value+=elem;
    }
</script>
<div id="box" >
    <textarea style="width:420px" name="posbox" id="posbox" rows="4" cols="70"></textarea>
    <textarea style="width:420px" name="nonbox" id="nonbox" rows="4" cols="70"></textarea>
    <textarea style="width:420px" name="negbox" id="negbox" rows="4" cols="70"></textarea>
</div>
```

However, this doesn't work. What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

Comment: The first thing I would do would be to fix your html. You have two pairs of body and html tags.

Answer (score 0):

make it simpler. Assumed that radios "name" is the same as the divs id where you take the content from:

```
...
<div id="teks'.$j.'">TEXT 2 </div>
<input type="radio" id="pos'. $j .'" name="teks'.$j.'" value="POS" 
   onclick="addPOS(this);">POS2</input>
<input type="radio" id="non'. $j .'" name="teks'.$j.'" value="NON" 
   onclick="addNON(this);">NON2</input>
...
```

you could just do:

```
function addPOS(elem)
{
    document.getElementById("posbox").value+=document.getElementById(elem.name).innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Axel thanks for the response. your answer seems not answer my question

Answer (score 0):

You making this too complicated, all you have to do is make a function, for example `Print()`
that would look like this where you defined it:

```
function Print(what,textareaobj)
{ 
  textareaobj.value=what
}
```

Then in the file that you are calling have a what variable set
for example

```
var what = "The text";
```

and for the button you add the attribute onclick="Print(what,getElementById('idoftextarea')" for example:

```
<button onclick="Print(what,getElementById('idoftextarea')">Click</button>
```

Comment: i'm not making this too complicate. in fact this is my case. thanks